# Rails Ajax Form not showing up (using remote:true)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Hi Guys im trying to render a partial using ajax remote true.

On my "new auction" link i have remote true inserted. 
I also have created a separate 'new.js.erb' file. When the 'new auction' link is clicked, my chrome console shows me status 200 OK. Also when i click response I can see that the 'new.js.erb' file is being read [image]. However the form i want to show up dosnt show up!

It dosnt give me any errors, so im not sure what to do or how to proceed?!

Here is the code inside my new.js.erb file:

```
$('#current_auctions').prepend("<%= j render partial: 'form' %>");
}
```

Here is the code for my actual form (_form.html.erb):

```
<div class="form-group" id="new_auction">
        <%=form_for @auction do |a|%>
        <%=a.label :titlee%>
        <%=a.text_field  :title, class:"form-control"%>
        <%=a.label :detailss%>
        <%=a.text_area :details,class:"form-control"%><br>
        <%=a.label :endz_onn%>
        <%=a.date_field :ends_on, class:"form-control"%><br>
        <%=a.label :reserve_pricee%>
        <%=a.number_field :reserve_price, class:"form-control"%><br>
        <%=a.submit "Create", class: "btn btn-default"%>
        <%end%>
        </div>
```

Here is the code for my index page(index.html.erb -This is where I want to prepend the new above form)

```
<div id="current_auctions">
<h3 class="heading"> Current Auctions </h3><hr>

<%@auctions.each do |auction| %>
  <strong><%=link_to auction.title, auction%><br></strong>
  <%=auction.details%><br><br>
  Ends on:<%=auction.ends_on%><br>
  Reserve Price:$<%=auction.reserve_price%><br>
  <hr>
<%end%> 
</div>
```

My link_to looks like this:

```
<%=link_to "New Auction", new_auction_path, remote: true%><br>
```

My routes look like this:[image]

If i prepend regular text, [image]it shows up, so I know its a problem with the way im rendering the partial, but it looks correct to me, I want to understand why its not working

I am using Ruby on Rails, Sublime Text 2, postgresql

Comment: Have you configured a route for your link to get/post to? If so can you add it to your question, please?

Comment: @NickM sorry for the incomplete post ,i just added the link_to

Comment: do you actually have a `#current_auctions`  on the page?

Comment: What about the route?

Comment: Can you show the .erb and the generated html page this is supposed to be  inserted into buy the JS?

Comment: Also if you can do a `rake routes` and post the relevant routes for auctions.

Comment: i just added a screenshot of the routes as well as the index.html.erb where I want the js form to prepend to

Comment: what happens in the rails server console when it tries to retrieve it? Do you see an error there?

Comment: no it also gives me a 200 OKAY.

Comment: if that's the case, then the form itself isn't rendering correctly, but the remote call seems like it is. What's your controller look like, is the @auction being set correctly? Add this to your `_form` `<%=@auctions.nil?%>` to see if that is being set...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a separate `<div>` for the form

in index.html.erb:

```
<div id="current_auctions">
  <div id="insert_form"> </div>
  <h3 class="heading"> Current Auctions </h3><hr>

  <%@auctions.each do |auction| %>
    <strong><%=link_to auction.title, auction%><br></strong>
    <%=auction.details%><br><br>
```

then use this in your partial:

```
$('#insert_form').html("<%= j render partial: 'form' %>");
```

Comment: adding a post method to my link gives me a :
POST http://localhost:3000/auctions/new 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I know it seems assumed, but maybe change `:method => :get`

Comment: i tried that, but gives me the same output as before (no errors, but no form being displayed)

Comment: Not being familiar with this, can you tell me what `j` is doing before the render? Also I see a `}` after that code in your question, what is before all of the code you posted? is that your entire new.js.erb file?

Answer (score 0):

I would add `id`directly to the link in `index.html.erb`

```
<%=link_to "New Auction", new_auction_path, id: 'new_auction_link' remote: true%><br>
```

and than in  `new.js.erb`

```
$('#new_auction_link').after('<%= j render 'form' %>');
```